# Meaning of a symbol character in python

Tags: python, sockets, networking

I am tring to figure what is the meaning of this character: `<I` in python.

As I saw in many python script who use sockets, they use this character as a "pack" and "unpack"
argument, so an explaination about this character will be great.

Answer (score 6):

From the [`struct`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) module docs...

```
<   little-endian
I   unsigned int    integer     4
```

...so `"<I"` means a 4-byte (32-bit) unsigned integer in [little-endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Little-endian) format, which can contain any integer value between 0 and 4,294,967,295.